# List integers to string using classes

Tags: python, list, class

I want to write a class for vectors, and I need to be able to cast the integers in the list to a string and print them.

Example:
[1,2.5] --> "<1,2.5>"

This is what I came up but its not working, any help would be appreciated.

```
class Vector(list):
def __init__(self,other):
    assert len(other)!=0, "Invalid Input!"
    for e in other:
        assert type(e)==int or type(e)==float, "Invalid Input!"
    list.__init__(self,other)
def __str__(self):
    s = ''
    for x in range (len(self)):
        s + = str(self.x)
    return s
```

Comment: `s + = str(self.x)`  maybe should be `s += str(self.x)`?  (no space between + and =)

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Please fix you indentation. Whitespace is very important in Python.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry in python it is correct when I copy paste to here it made like this.

Comment: Please fix it here. And post your error. Your class does not have an attribute `x`

Comment: @MadPhysicist don't worry it worked :D someone answered and I checked it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the join function to combine itself.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "<%s>" % ", ".join(self)
```

Join will basically return a string of the content of the list separated by a comma and a space. We then put the angle brackets in the string that we combine it with.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I am getting this error when I implement your code: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Use `return f"<%s>" % ", ".join(map(str, self))`

Comment: You are amazing :3 Thank you!

Comment: A minor improvment - string.format() is generally preferred over the % operator these days.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `f`-strings

```
def __str__(self):
    return(f'<{super().__str__()[1:-1]}>')
```